# Maximize a definite integral with constraints on the limits

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I would like to maximize the following definite double integral with respect to $0<r<\frac{1}{2}$:

$\int _0^{\frac{d}{1-r}}\int _{\frac{d+r x-x}{r}}^s [(1-r) x+r y -d]dydx$

under the constraints: $0\leq d \leq 1$, $2d < s \leq 4$, $0 < r < \frac{1}{2}$, $0 \leq x \leq s$, $0\leq y \leq s$.

Note that the variables of integration, i.e. $x$ and $y$, are both bounded by $0$ and $s$; for this reason, I have to be careful in my code regarding the limits of integration regions.

Here is my code:

```
maxR = Flatten[Table[{d, s, r /. Last@Maximize[{Integrate[(1 - r)*x + r*y - d, {x, 0, Min[s, d/(1 - r)]}, {y, Max[0, Min[s, (d + r*x - x)/r]], s}], 0 <= d <= 1, 2 d < s, 0 < r < 1/2}, {r}]}, {d, 0, 1, .1}, {s, 1, 4, .1}], 1];
ListPlot3D[maxR, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"d", "s", "r"}]
```

And this is running forever. Can anyone help please?

By the way, this is an extension of Ulich's answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202468/solving-a-definite-integral-with-constraints-on-the-limits/202534#202534). While the latter shows how to get the solution of the integral, my question here regards a maximization of the integral.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving a definite integral with constraints on the limits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202468/solving-a-definite-integral-with-constraints-on-the-limits)

Comment: In [202468](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202468/solving-a-definite-integral-with-constraints-on-the-limits/202534#202534) we elaborated the integral numerically. Why didn't you use this result?

Comment: @AccidentalFourier Transform, I have added an explanation that this post is not a duplicate of [that post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202468/solving-a-definite-integral-with-constraints-on-the-limits/202534#202534).

Comment: @Ulrich, since my code in this post is part of a larger context, I utilized your suggestion about modifying the integration limits to my current code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Integrate[...]` substituded by the result from question [202534](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202468/solving-a-definite-integral-with-constraints-on-the-limits/202534?noredirect=1#comment523997_202534)

```
int[s_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[(1 - r)*x + r*y - d, {x, 0, Min[s, d/(1 - r)]}, {y,Max[0, Min[s, (d + r*x - x)/r]], s}]
```

the solution can be obtained numerically:

```
Table[NMaximize[{int[s, d, r], 0 < r < 1/2}, { r}], {d, 0,1, .1}, {s, 1, 4, .1 }]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Ulrich! It was very helpful!